# Show that $\lambda(E) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(E)}{2^{n}}$ is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I just completed my proof for the following measure theory problem and just wanted to make sure my work is correct:

> Let $(\mu_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of meaures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ with $\mu_{n}(\Omega) \leq 1$ and define $\lambda: \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$\lambda(E) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(E)}{2^{n}}.$$ Show that $\lambda$ is a measure and that $\mu_{n} \ll \lambda$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($\mu_{n}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$).

$a)$ First we need to show that $\lambda(\emptyset)=0.$ Since $$\lambda(E) := \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(E)}{2^{n}}$$ Where $\mu_{n}$ is a sequence of measures, then $$\lambda(\emptyset) := \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(\emptyset)}{2^{n}}\displaystyle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{0}{2^{n}}=0.$$ Now, we need to show that for a sequence of sets $A_{1},A_{2}...\in \mathcal{F}$ where $A_{i}\cap A_{j} = \emptyset $ for all $i \neq j$ we have that $\lambda(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(A_{n}).$ Therefore, computing $\lambda$ applied to a union of pairwise disjoint sets yields:

\begin{align*}
\lambda(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}) &= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n})}{2^{n}} \\ 
&= 2^{-n} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{n}) \ \ \text{since $\mu_{n}$ is a measure $\forall n$} \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(A_{n})}{2^{n}}
\end{align*}

completing the proof and hence $\lambda$ is a measure.

$b)$ Now to show that $\mu_{n} \ll \lambda$ $\forall n$, it is easy to see that since $$\lambda(E) := \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu_{n}(E)}{2^{n}}$$ and so if $\lambda(E)=0$ then $\mu_{n} = 0$ since the value of $\lambda$ applied to $E$ is determined by the value of $\mu_{n}$ applied to $E$ for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\mu_{n} \ll \lambda$ $\forall n._{\square}$

Comment: When you compute the $\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$, replace the index $n$ for, say, $k$. Otherwise, we end up using the same index for the sets and the measures when you are in fact summing over two different indices.

Comment: Part b) is pretty obvious, but note that it will be easier to communicate your logic if you argue by contradiction.

Comment: @Quoka - Based off your second comment for part b), do you mind elaborating on this argument by contradiction? I tried formulating it but feel a little lost. Feel free to make it into a second answer, i'd be more than happy to give a (+1). :-)

Comment: By way of contradiction, suppose that $\lambda(E) = 0$ but $\mu_n(E) \neq 0$. Then $\mu_n(E) > 0$ and $0 = \lambda(E) = \sum_{k}\frac{\mu_k(E)}{2^k} \ge 2^{-n}\mu_n(E) > 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (a), second property, there is an added factor. Should be
$$\lambda(\cup_{n}A_n)=\sum_k\frac{\mu_k(\cup_n A_n)}{2^k}=\sum_k\sum_n\frac{\mu_k(A_n)}{2^k} =\sum_n\sum_k \frac{\mu_k(A_n)}{2^k}=\sum_n\lambda(A_n)$$